# Постоянно работающий поиск

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, thymeleaf, datatable

У меня есть кнопки передающие значения в `<input>`, но чтобы поиск сработал приходится использовать event по типу focus или keyup. Как после нажатия кнопки и передачи значения в поиск происходил автоматический поиск без наведения?

Comment: "поиск без наведения" - что это значит вообще? Вы хотите в любом месте сайта начать печатать текст и автоматиечски, чтобы это вставлялось в поиск?

Comment: Написал же, после нажатия кнопки передается значение в поле поиска. И хочу чтобы оно сразу искалось.

Comment: Т.е. искать при вводе каждого символа, а не по нажатию на кнопку?

Comment: [HTMLElement: input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

Answer (score 0):

Можно слушать событие ввода (input):

```js
const input = document.getElementById("search");
const res = document.getElementById("res");
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  res.innerText = input.value;
});
```

```html
<input id="search" type="search">
<br>
<span id="res"></span>
```